# Run GUI app from php/web page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create an application running  in my browser, using php, html and javascript/JQuery.
And my question is how to can I run some gui app, and/or user input require application?
I try in php shell_exec(), exec(), and system(), and it dosn't work for me
From example I want to run something like gnome-terminal -e ssh user@host or 'firefox google.com'

I know that is some method to do that in Windows OS, but my application is designed for Linux users

Is any method in php / javascript / html to run app in that way? Or should I use some other web developing language to achieve my task?

Edit: I want to add that this web app is designed to run localy (127.0.0.1), not over the web. And i only want to run applications only on the local machine where the app is hosted.

Comment: You can't really take a GUI app and display it to your users in the way that you described.  You'd have to create a GUI with HTML/CSS and have that interact with your PHP server.  Maybe if you expand I could better help?

Comment: Also, beware of `exec()` commands.  There be dragons down that path (if you don't know what you're doing)

Comment: "I know that is some method to do that in Windows OS". What do you mean by this? Can you give an example? AFAIK you can't just embed Windows desktop apps in a browser. Same goes for Linux desktop/console apps, or any other OS, regardless of the what system the server or client is running. If you want users to be able to call up Linux apps remotely, look into forwarding X over SSH, and forget the web. But, if as stated you only want to run this in localhost, then what exactly is the point? If you're already on the machine, just run the app normally...